# Retrieving list of objects from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a listbox with listboxitems.
In the listboxitems, I have domain objects.
How kan I converse the listbox's items to a list of domain objects?
I now have something like this:

```
List<DomainObject> list = theListBox.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .Select(item => item.Content)
                             .ToList();
```

This isn't working...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I'm going to give an example of my domainobject class because I wasn't very clear:

```
public class Person
{
    public int personId{get;set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public double price{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    {

        return name;
    }
```

These objects are stored in the listboxitems via the .content property.
Now I just want a list of those PersonObject that are in the listboxitems of the listbox.

Comment: _"This isn't working..."_ Was that the error message you got?

Comment: *In the listboxitems, I have domain objects.*
How do you store *domain objects* in *listboxitems*, ?

Comment: Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.DomainObject>'

Comment: via it's content property.

Comment: Edited my post to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the output to the `DomainObject` in the `Select()` method, for sample:

```
List<DomainObject> list = theListBox.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                          .Select(item => new DomainObject() { Content = item.Content})
                          .ToList();
```

I am not sure about what property the `DomainObject` type has, but you could fill these properties in the object initialization.

Comment: That one is going into the right direction, but now I'm getting this error: Error 3 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Call `.Cast<ListViewItem>` before calling `Select()`.